# rTorrent access tracker with proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, socks-proxy, rtorrent

all tracker domain was blocked in my ISP

I can create proxy with `ssh -D` and use `privoxy` to trans socks5 proxy to http proxy, the proxy works well

How I can use proxy it only when rTorrent access tracker (not all connect) ?

thanks

Comment: [Tixati](http://www.tixati.com/download/linux.html), [Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) have option enable proxy for tracker only. And in future can you add tag linux/unix so this questions will be hidden for me.

Comment: only your torrent client can provide this feature. if rtorrent doesn't, I know for a fact that deluge does.

Answer (score 3):

The `rtorrent.rc` file has this:

```
network.http.proxy_address.set = 192.168.1.1:8118
```

which can be used for http(S) tracker connections.